# Pulling from UserDefaults for a Picker

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I feel like I must be doing something stupid. All I'm trying to do if pull from UserDefaults to set a Picker value, then save to UserDefaults when the Picker changes. The issue I'm running into comes when I try and make the code work for iOS14 and 15.

```
struct SettingsView: View {

    @State var rangeSelection: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "vocalRange")

    @State var rangeOptions = ["Soprano", "Mezzo-Soprano/Alto", "Extended Range"]
    
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack{
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker(selection: $rangeSelection, label: Text("Range")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< rangeOptions.count, id: \.self) { range in
                            Text(rangeOptions[range])
                                    .tag(range)
                        }
                    }
                    .onChange(of: rangeSelection, perform: { value in
                        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(rangeSelection, forKey: "vocalRange")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Settings")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine, and the 'onChange' fires great. Only weird thing is, if you leave the page and immediately go back in, the 'rangeSelection' variable resets to what it was originally. Once you restart the app however, the change is reflected correctly.

---

As an alternative, I tried the following

```
 @State var rangeSelection: Int = 0

...
    .onAppear(perform:{
        rangeSelection = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "vocalRange")
    })
```

This creates another fun issue. In iOS15 it works fine, but in iOS14, once you've changed the picker, the OnAppear fires before the OnChange, and reverts the Picker back to its previous value. This only happens because I'm using the picker in a Form/List, so it changes pages when you select the Picker.

I feel like there is an obvious solution I should be using.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/66730876/12299030?

Comment: I don't think so :( My issue seems to stem from using the List picker style, instead of a SegmentedPicker like in the question above. I'm using the first kind in this image, which is why when the user changes the value in the picker, OnAppear fires again. "https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*ksvO_QqOxxe3T-AIXU5iYQ.png"

Comment: what's a `List picker style`? I don't see the `.pickerStyle(...)` in your code. Are you showing us code that you are not using?

Comment: Use AppStorage that way it will save as well

Comment: @loremipsum Aha!! Somehow I didn't know of the existence of AppStorage. Implemented and worked perfect thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @loremipsum I used AppStorage. I declared the variable like this, and no 'onChange' was needed!

```
@AppStorage("vocalRange") var rangeSelection: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "vocalRange")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set delay in .OnAppear method to work it

```
.onAppear(perform:{
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
     rangeSelection = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "vocalRange")
    }
})
```